# send updated file to remote server

Tags: php, nginx

I have one server that has php installed (server 1). I have another server that only has nginx installed (server2).

Server 1 updates a file via php.

As an example the file might be called "hello.html" and this file needs to be updated every hour. "hello.html" is a static file after the php has been run.

Server 2 also has a file called "hello.html" which cannot update because there is no php on server 2 (i do not want php on server 2 because server 2 is only a static file web server and nothing else).

My ideal goal is to have server 1 update "hello.html" and then send it to server 2 and overwrite it in the web directory. This way anyone who went to "mydomain.com/hello.html" would receive the latest updated file.

My question is how do I get the updated static files from server 1 to server 2?

Hopefully example code would be included in answers. Thanks.

Comment: php has ftp functions

Comment: php has alot of functions. A useful answer would be "using the php ftp function may help, here is an example of the code you would use."

Comment: for that kind of answer, feel free to hire me.

Comment: how do i do that? Again, a useful answer would be " for that you can hire me, here is how to hire me."

Comment: @Pat Dagon has summed up your question in one..

Comment: wow, thanks for the warm welcome. I was being serious. I would pay someone to answer this no prob. You said to hire you, i thought "i would love to hire someone", but I do not know how to hire you, and you did not provide that information.

Comment: @Pat You want an example? http://www.php.net/ftp   Happy reading.

Comment: Thanks Daryl I have researched the php ftp functions at that very page already. I know that it would be best if I could take a php.net page and work with it, but I have had problems doing so. I am really hoping for some example code using server 1 and server 2. I do not know where to ftp it or how to request the updated ftp files and move them to the web directory, etc. I am hoping for an example. Thanks again.

Comment: Assuming you can explore other options than PHP, because you only care about the end result:  A) If they're on the same local area network, you could do a network volume mount via `nfs`. You effectively make a directory on ServerA also a directory on ServerB -- or vice versa.  So you could be writing to a file that physically exists on ServerA or SeverB from either server.  B) You could use a scheduled task on ServerA to `rsync` a file or directory on ServerA to ServerB.

Comment: dictating to others how they should answer you on a free 'public' forum is not a great way to make friends

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I am researching that as well. You are right that I only want the end result. I would use anything to do this. Since I am new to unix,  nfs looks a little scary. I am willing to learn it (or anything) I just want to make sure that (nfs) would accomplish the goal. If it will, I will spend a few days learning about it so I can use it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @dagon How can I hire you as you suggested?

Comment: it was sarcasm, while i am a php devloper, i don't do this kind of work

Comment: @dagon aaaah, Maybe you should post things at "sarcasm overflow" :)

Answer (score -2):

make the HTML file a iframe to your other domain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This would not be ideal for me, though it would do the trick. The goal of server 2 is to serve static files as quick as possible. I need the updated static files to be located on server 2